# Error generating <DbContext>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, code-first, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am trying stuff out on MVC4 Beta. Project is in VS11, EF 5.0-Beta, using Code First approach.
Created simple Model poco and DbContext derived class with single IDbSet<> property for model class. Connection string with LocalDb.

I noticed when context's Entity Set property is type of IDbSet<> then I get message from VS when I try to create new controller with “Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework” Scaffolding template:
"There was an error generating 'MyProject.MyNamespace.MyContext'. Try rebuilding your project."
Even Clean Solution and building again doesn’t help.

If I changed Entity Set property to type DbSet<> then controller scaffolding succeeds.
Is it a bug or is it expectable?

Br,
Lauri

Answer (score -1):

It is not a bug you cant instantiate an instance of an Interface.  The I in front of IDbSet denotes the type as an interface (By convention).  So you were trying to create an instance of that interface.  Instead you need to delcare it with DBSet<> which is an implementation of the IDBSet<> interface.  I hope this clarifies your issue.

Comment: OK, but after scaffolding with DbSet<> properties I can change them to IDbSet<> and application builds and works. Is it result of .Net type resolving or something in that nature?

Comment: The correct syntax is to use DbSet<> and not IDbBSet<> as far as i know